# Interacting with content behind Bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap in an AngularJS project for modal popups.

The modal has a parent div like this:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope responsiveModal in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="responsiveModal" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
```

This parent container covers the whole screen and prevents the user from interacting with elements beside or below the modal. Is there any way to change this?

I also tried `'backdrop: false,'` in the modal options.

Comment: Are you using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: Yes I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap.

Comment: If u could post a fiddle i ll help u... I fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Without modifying Bootstrap itself, no**. If you're willing to do that, then yes, but it won't be simple.

That being said, I feel obligated to point out that **a modal view is, by definition, supposed to block input outside of itself until the user is done interacting with it.** If you want them to be able to interact with other things while it is up, that's not a modal. That's a popup. That's why they don't have anything in place to allow interactions outside of the modal.